# wrong Redhat package name to be updated

Tags: redhat, rpm

I have installed Redhat linux package `v6.7`. When i run command `rpm -qa | grep redhat-release`. It returns  `redhat-release-server-6Server_6.7.0.3_el6.x87_64`; I want to edit this result to `redhat-release-server-6.7.0.3_el6.x87_64`. Can I edit some configuration file to update this?

Comment: You should avoid editing system files Just to obtain a favourable results. 
Instead, you can use awk, cut , sed and other tools present in linux to modify the output according to your use case.

Comment: You cannot do this by editing a configuration file, but you could use `rpmbuild` (`rpmrebuild -e redhat-release-server-6Server_6.7.0.3_el6.x86_64`) to create a new rpm file with an edited name/version. You could then delete the old package and install this one instead. However, other packages may depend on this one and deletion will fail. Also I really got to ask why you would need this.